# How to switch on snap option in QGIS 2.18 when creating customize polygon

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2, snapping, qgsmapcanvas

How to switch on snap option in QGIS 2.18 when creating customize polygon as in:

```
class customPoly(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):

def __init__(self, iface):
    self.iface = iface
    QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.iface.mapCanvas()) 
    self.rubber=None
    self.dup_Pt=None
    self.cnt=0
    .....

def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button()==Qt.LeftButton:
        if self.draggable:
            self.pos=event.pos()
            mapping_Pt, lyrPt=self.transformCoordinates(self.pos)
            ....
            self.rubber.addPoint(mapping_Pt,self.cnt+1)
            self.dup_Pt.addPoint(mapPt,self.cnt+1)

            ....
```

The above code is part of custom polygon, I want to know, how to switch on snapping while picking point or `QgsMapToolEmitPoint` or in `canvasPressEvent(self, event)` or any other best option to switch on snap while in pick point while creating custom polygon